# Angular $resource and poorly formatted JSONP

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get data from a third party service (Comic Vine) but my application is Javascript-only so I have to resort to JSONP.
When I receive a response from the server, Angular raises an error like it can't interpret correctly the response received like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I'm not an expert with JSONP but from what I gather, this could be due to a pretty common error that JSONP responses should consist of a Javascript function and not an object like it happens in this case. This is an example of the response I get (only the first line):

```
{"error":"OK","limit":100,"offset":0,"number_of_page_results":100,"number_of_total_results":2487,"status_code":1,"results":[{"aliases":null,"api_detail_url":"http:\/\/www.comicvine.com\/api\/issue\/4000-313848\/","cover_date":"2005-10-
```

This is the part of my code where I configure the $resource service:

```
angular.module('comicVineServices', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Issue', ['$resource', function($resource){

    return $resource(
        {
            api_key:'03f2238446ecacab80ae361aa064014a7e416688',
            query: 'green',
            resources:'issue',
            format: 'json',
            callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
        },
        {
            query: {
                method: 'JSONP',
                responseType: 'json',
                isArray: false,

            }
        }
    );
}]);
```

I've tried to parse the response myself or at least see if I can intercept it before it's parsed with `transformResponse` and an `interceptor` but no success so far.

Do you guys think a malformed response could be the problem (an object when it should be a function)?
Do you guys think there any work around that I can do on my side?

Comment: If the server does not support jsonp then I don't think there is anything you can do.  Try the request with a plain GET.  If you see some response headers with Access-Control-Allow- then it means the site supports CORS which is a good thing.  It's just a matter of getting the headers right and you can do regular cross-domain queries.

Comment: I'm confused about the statement "my application is Javascript-only so I have to resort to JSONP".  It would be the server that dictates which technologies can be consumed, not the client.

Comment: Guys, it's a third party API.
They do provide GET access but not for client-only applications and they do provide JSONP access because they know they don't allow GET access from client-only applications.
Problem is that their JSONP response is an object instead of a function.